# Tumblr read more expand on the same page

Tags: tumblr, expand

I'm developing a Tumblr site.
When the user clicks on the "read more", the content is revealed and expanded on the same page,how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Tumblr is reworking the UI for editing, the Read More tool may have been hidden from you.  Reset your preferences to use the Rich Text Editor to edit posts.  The Read More tool is between the bulleted list tool and the image tool.  See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I found how to replace the "read more" to what I want with {READ MORE}
but I need to remove the redirect {Permalink}.
I want to open in the same window,than I add "Read more" from Rich Text Editor.

Comment: I don't think this response answers the question posed.  At any reate, to do what @zumza wants will require a small bit of JavaScript + Ajax to load the entire contents of the post , using either a) the Tumblr API or b) by loading the post's Permalink page with an Ajax call and parsing out the body of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It's a simple script, but it works. Add this code in your theme before tag  (or as it should be):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.spa').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().children('div.spb').toggle('normal');
      return false;
     });
    });
    </script>


<style type="text/css">
.spb{display:none;}
.spa{cursor:pointer;display:block;} 
.spa:after{display:block;content: "{lang:Read more}";margin-bottom:10px;} 
</style>
```

Now, when you write a new text, add to it those things.

```html
    Text before Spoiler
    <a href="" class="spa"></a>
     <div class="spb">
    Text after Spoiler
     </div>
```